# What's the difference between these two typedefs?

Tags: c++, android-ndk

What is the difference between the two marked lines in the code below?

```
template <const char *N> struct A {
    static const char *p;
    };

template <class T> struct B {
    static const char c[1];
    typedef A<B<T>::c> C;   // <---
    // typedef A<c> C;      // <---
    };
```

Error that i recived is:

> test_t.C: In instantiation of 'const char B::c [1]':
>   test_t.C:7:   instantiated from here
>   test_t.C:7: internal compiler error: in instantiate_decl, at cp/pt.c:15628
>   Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.
>   See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html for instructions.

Comment: Why is it that people insist on tagging questions with the [tag:c] tag, when it clearly can't be C code because it uses things like templates?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's no difference. Why do you think there is one?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I'm pretty sure it's because of that whole "C/C++" nonsense.

Comment: typedef A<B<T>::c> C; - this one provide compiler error;
 typedef A<c> C;  - this one all ok.

Comment: @Pepelac: I get no error from either; the question would be easier to answer if you showed us the error, rather than making us guess how your compiler behaves. Also, which compiler are you using?

Comment: That is an *internal compiler error*, and it is a bug of the compiler as you are hinted by the message: *Please submit a full bug report, ... See http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html* Is it **so hard** to read error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"internal compiler error"* roughly translates as *"You may have supplied broken code, or reasonable but confusing code. Either way, you're out of luck. Please get the next release version and hope for the best."*

Comment: Well, you can actually file a bug report to increase the chances of the bug being fixed rather than just *hoping for the best*. You make your own luck here (or at least you can have an effect)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: fair enough; perhaps I am being a little too cynical ;-) The standard NDK compiler is a few minor releases behind the current version of GCC, so it isn't unreasonable in this case to assume that the problem has already been fixed in the mainline and is just awaiting a merge and fresh release from Google.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler has a bug, and fails to compile the first form.

Since the two forms are equivalent, you can work around the bug using the second form. It might also be worth trying a more recent compiler version (if there is one) to see if the bug has been fixed.